# Python: Corrupted output from script

Tags: python, multithreading, stdout

I have the following Python script which I use to ping a list of IPs passed on the command line.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys, time
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
from Queue import Queue
num_threads = 255
queue = Queue()
p=0
f=0
t=0

def timestamp():
    lt = time.localtime(time.time())
    return "%02d.%02d.%04d %02d:%02d:%02d" % (lt[2], lt[1], lt[0], lt[3], lt[4], lt[5])

def pinger(i, q):
    global p
    global f

    while True:
        ip = q.get()
        ret = subprocess.call("ping -c 2 %s" % ip,
                        shell=True,
                        stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        if ret == 0:
            print(ip+"\tpassed")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            p+=1
        else:
            print(ip+"\tfailed")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            f+=1
        q.task_done()

for i in range(num_threads):

    worker = Thread(target=pinger, args=(i, queue))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

print("\nStarted at "+timestamp())

for ip in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines():
    ip=ip.strip()
    queue.put(ip)
    t+=1

queue.join()
print(str(t) + " IPs pinged, " + str(p) + " passed, " + str(f) + " failed\n")
print("\nFinished at "+timestamp())
```

For the most part the output is perfect like this, tab separated ready for Excel

```
192.168.188.1   failed
192.168.199.107 passed
192.168.7.2     passed
192.168.199.108 failed
```

But every time, and at random, I get problems with the output for example odd indent on a line

```
192.168.164.173 failed
 192.168.164.190        failed
```

Or odd indent in one field - here the IP is indented but not the message

```
 172.29.19.132  failed
```

or concatenation followed by a blank line

```
172.29.9.37     passed172.29.19.133     passed

172.29.9.39     passed
```

And combinations of these not always the same IPs. 
I've ensured the ip list is clean, and tried reducing the thread count, introducing delays to printing, and flushing STDOUT to no avail. Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you try with locks ? Locking the 'print' section.

Comment: Alternatively don't print while processing. Do the testing work, adding results to a dict - then print them at the end of the process. This also makes re-formatting them easier in future if you need a different output structure (e.g. html table)

Comment: Ok I will try the dictionary approach. Farbiondriven. Is this what you mean by locking the print section?

Comment: Brilliant chaps many thanks. I researched the lock and replaced my print lines with for example  "print "{0}\n".format(ip+"\tfailed"),"  and all is now fine